# How to cut polygons to fit grid ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, mapping

I have a map that displays the distribution of different types of karst all over the US. The different types of soil are portrayed through polygons. I've also created a grid that divides the US, and the endgame here is to be able to analyze the fraction of karst within each grid box (i.e. use a command in arcpy or a geoprocessing tool that searches through all the gridboxes and gives back a table with all the labeled gridboxes with their respective fraction of karst). I have two issues here:

1. When the gridbox is created, I'm pretty sure the polygons aren't "cut" to conform to the lines of the grid. These are very complicated shapes that overlap the gridlines, so is there a way to cut these polygons so that when I go in and calculate the fraction of karst within each gridbox, the program will calculate JUST the karst info that lies within the confines of that gridbox?
2. What kind of command/tool would I be able to use to search through all the gridboxes and return the fraction of karst within each one?

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and edit your question to only include one question.  Though, that being said, I highly recommend you look into [Tabulate Intersection](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/tabulate-intersection.htm) tools. The link points to Pro, but I regularly use it in desktop, just couldn't quickly find as concise of a link.